# How to query DynomoDB and return key value pairs as strings

Tags: c#, logging, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to query a DynamoDB that i have created using code from the Amazon docs with a few simple modifications. I'm trying to take the data i get and write it to a log file as strings. But all i can seem to get is this:

2013-02-22 20:21:37.9268|Trace|[System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+KeyCollection[System.String,Amazon.DynamoDB.Model.AttributeValue] System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+ValueCollection[System.String,Amazon.DynamoDB.Model.AttributeValue]]|

I've tried a few different things but all return either the same thing, or something very similar.

The code i'm using:

```
  private static void GetCallsForRange()
  {
     AmazonDynamoDBConfig config = new AmazonDynamoDBConfig();
     config.ServiceURL = "http://dynamodb.us-west-2.amazonaws.com";
     AmazonDynamoDBClient client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(config);


     DateTime startDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-21);
     string start = startDate.ToString("G", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);

     DateTime endDate = DateTime.Today;
     string end = endDate.ToString("G", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);

     QueryRequest request = new QueryRequest
     {
        TableName = "Inquiry",
        HashKeyValue = new AttributeValue { S = "+15555555555" },
        RangeKeyCondition = new Condition
        {
           ComparisonOperator = "BETWEEN",
           AttributeValueList = new List<AttributeValue>()
           {
              new AttributeValue { S = start },
              new AttributeValue { S = end }
           }
        }
     };


     QueryResponse response = client.Query(request);
     QueryResult result = response.QueryResult;


     foreach (Dictionary<string, AttributeValue> item in response.QueryResult.Items)
     {
        string logMsg = String.Format("[{0} {1}]", item.Keys, item.Values);
        Logging.LogTrace(logMsg);
     }

  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to iterate over each item in the `response.QueryResult.Items`.  You could rewrite your loop like this (taken from the Amazon DynamoDB documentation):

```
foreach (Dictionary<string, AttributeValue> item in response.QueryResult.Items) 
{
     LogItem(item);
}
private void LogItem(Dictionary<string, AttributeValue> attributeList)
{
     foreach (KeyValuePair<string, AttributeValue> kvp in attributeList)
     {
          string attributeName = kvp.Key;
          AttributeValue value = kvp.Value;
          string logValue = 
               (value.S == null ? "" : value.S) +
               (value.N == null ? "" : value.N.ToString()) +
               (value.B == null ? "" : value.B.ToString()) +
               (value.SS == null ? "" : string.Join(",", value.SS.ToArray())) +
               (value.NS == null ? "" : string.Join(",", value.NS.ToArray())) +
               (value.BS == null ? "" : string.Join(",", value.BS.ToArray()));
          string logMsg = string.Format("[{0} {1}]", attributeName, logValue);
          Logging.LogTrace(logMsg);
     }
}
```

Essentially, you need to discover the "type" of the `AttributeValue`(String, Number, Binary, StringSet, NumberSet, BinarySet) and then output that to your log.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Yes that helps a lot! So close now. Im still kind of new to this, so im not getting it quite right. The only issues i seem to be having are that LogItem(item) throws an error saying "An object reference is required for non-static field". Should LogItem be a static method?

Comment: And i get an error for this line: (value.BS == null ? "" : string.Join(",", value.BS.ToArray()));


"The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'string.Join<System.IO.MemoryStream>(string, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.IO.MemoryStream>)' and 'string.Join(string, params object[])'"

Comment: Sorry, yes the method should be static.  I missed the fact that your original method was static.